# Модификаторы доступа методов с аннотациями @PostConstruct и @PreDestroy

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, доступ, spring-core

Очень часто вижу в коде по инициализации бинов модификатор `public` у методов с аннотациями `@PostConstruct` и `@PreDestroy`.

Разве это не нарушает инкапсуляцию? Ведь эти методы не должны быть доступны никому кроме контекста спринга.

Не правильнее было бы их сделать `private`? Допускается ли использовать `public` и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это не проблема.

Методы помеченные `@PostConstruct` и `@PreDestroy` являются частью открытого интерфейса вашего класса, так как только с помощью них можно правильно создать или уничтожить объект, а значит они должны быть доступны клиентам класса. И у вас обычно больше одного клиента - второй это тесты.

Важное замечание касательно `@PostConstruct`: что если возникла необходимость использовать эту аннотацию, то это уже признак проблем в дизайне. По хорошему, инициализация и установка инвариантов должна происходить в конструкторе. То есть нужно использовать внедрение зависимостей через конструктор и не использовать `@PostConstruct` вообще и внедрение зависимостей через сеттеры, что может приводить к не полностью инициализированному объекту.

Comment: То есть предпочтительнее использовать public?